# How to get a specific value from a JSON object, like a name?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, http, glassfish

I use Angular as the front end of my application. For the backend I use glassfish. I currently use a Http GET verb to get a JSON object with an id and name and address. I only want to get the name of the object, how do I do that in a typescript file? How do I get the name of the newest added object of the rest server?

I want to get restaurantName from the object:

```
{ restaurantId: 1, restaurantName: 'Mcdonalds', restaurantAdres: 'Kalverstraat 5' },
```

Code that retrieves the object from the rest server:

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant')
      .subscribe(
        val => {
          const restStr = JSON.stringify(val);
          console.log(restStr);

    );
```

Backend code:

```
@GET

  @Produces("application/json")
  public Response all(){
    List<Restaurant> all = repositoryService.getAllRestaurants();
    return  Response
      .status(200)
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .entity(all)
      .build();
  }
```

```
 public List<Restaurant> getAllRestaurants() {
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = em.createQuery("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r").getResultList();
    em.close();
    return restaurants;
  }
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name = "Restaurant.findOne", query = "select m from Restaurant m where m.id = :id"),
  @NamedQuery(name = "Restaurant.getAll", query = "select m from Restaurant m")
})
public class Restaurant implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;



//    @Column(name="naam")
//    @NotBlank
//    private String naam;

  //    @NotBlank
  String restaurantName;


  //    @NotBlank
  String restaurantAdres;


  int restaurantId;

  public Restaurant(){

  }


  public Restaurant(int restaurantId, String restaurantName, String restaurantAdres) {
    this.restaurantId = restaurantId;
    this.restaurantName = restaurantName;
    this.restaurantAdres = restaurantAdres;
  }
```

Comment: are you trying get just the name when angular calls the http so the backend returns just the name or when you have received the object from the backend then on the angular side just get the name?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd create a class and maybe an interface to give you strongly typed objects in your TypeScript:

Then you can return the object from your get request as that object and use that however you want like `result.restaurantName`

A quick mock of what that looks like (using a stub method instead of http) [is here:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zaasje)

In short though:

the class and interface for Angular:

```
export interface IRestaurant {
   restaurantId: number;
   restaurantName: string;
   restaurantAddres: string;
}

export class Restaurant implements IRestaurant {
    restaurantId:number;
    restaurantName:string;
    restaurantAddres:string;
}
```

And then the component that gets the data via a method, and uses essentially the JSON as an object:

```
export class AppComponent  {
favoriteRestaurant: IRestaurant;

  retrieve(){
    this.favoriteRestaurant = this.getRestaurant();

    alert(this.favoriteRestaurant.restaurantName);
  }

  getRestaurant():IRestaurant {
    var result: Restaurant = {
       restaurantId: 1, 
       restaurantName: 'Mcdonalds',
       restaurantAddres: 'Kalverstraat 5'
    };

    return result;
  }
}
```

Making it more useful for you though, change the http.get method to something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/aquadine-jee/resources/restaurant')
      .subscribe(
        val:IRestaurant => {
          this.favoriteRestaurant = val;
          console.log(restStr.restaurantName);    
    );
```

You don't want to use JSON.stringify above, because that gives you a string!
Additionally, your restaurantAddress is mispelled, these would need to match exactly. So I would correct the backend.

Comment: If this is what you need, don't forget to unsubscribe from the Observable during the ngOnInit()